# Is Using Deprecated Google Infographics API a Good Idea

Tags: api, google-api, qr-code, deprecated

So I have recently found out about Google Infographics QR Codes API which is very easy to use and I have yet to find a better alternative. Example: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=Example:

[image: example QR code from Google Infographics QR Codes]

However their documentation page (https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes) says this: Warning: This API is deprecated. Please use the actively maintained Google Charts API instead. See our deprecation policy for details.

Also Google Infographics main page(https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/) says the fallowing:

Deprecation notice
While the separate Google Charts service is actively maintained, the infographics service was deprecated in 2012 and turned off on March 18, 2019.
Go to Google Charts

About Google Infographics
This deprecated API serves static PNG images via URLs you can place in the src attribute of an  tag.

As you can see eventhough Google says that it is turned off the API for QR Codes still works fine. Does this mean that I can still use this API with no worries? If not is there an equivalent API?

Answer (score 0):

Using a deprecated anything is never a good idea. deprecation notices are there to tell developers that they need to move away from something because its due to be shut down.

If its deprecated that means they will turn it off.   They start turning it off on "March 18, 2019".  It can take a while for it to be completely turned off and some APIs continue to work for a year or so before they stop working all together.

I would not use this or develop with it as it is going to stop working soon.

Recommendations of equivalent APIs is out of scope for Stack overflow i suggest you Google it.